# Django aggregate second-degree many-to-many relations

Tags: django

Apologies for the difficult title, but I essentially have a model `Foo` that has multiple `Bar` objects (i.e. `Foo.bar_set.all()` gives me all the `Bar` objects). Also, each `Bar` object has multiple `Baz` objects in the same manner.

Is there any way to access all the `Baz` objects that belong to the `Bar` objects of `Foo`? Something like `Foo.bar_set.all().baz_set.all()` would be convenient...

As of now I'm just loading `Foo.bar_set.all()`, iterating through the `bar`'s, and aggregating a set of `foo`'s. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this? Here I'm assuming `Baz` has a field `bar` which is a `ForeignKey` to `Bar`:

```
Baz.objects.filter(bar__in=foo.bar_set.all())
```